# Laptop Fan is CPU dependent and doesn't increase speed when gpu is even burning

Tags: laptop, overheating, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

The problem isn't personal and a lot of Ubuntu users which has no pwm control of their fan, can use this kind of workaround.

The fan of my laptop is CPU dependent, and doesn't care about Nvidia GPU's temperature, only increases speed when CPU temperature affects GPU temperature. But it's not that much ofc. I already cleaned dust and refreshed thermal paste.

I tried a lot of things with `sensors-detect` and `lm-sensors` or `grub` settings and many of other packages which I seen on other questions. But unfortunately my system hasn't control of pwm sensors of fan.

And I use both, Intel® HD Graphics 4600 is very okay for me, for desktop usage. And I'm using nvidia gtx960m on background, with `bumblebee`. But it was like this before too, when not using `bumblebee`.

**What can I do as a workaround?**

*Clevo-W230SD* laptop with *intel HM87* mainboard, ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. Just after booting, fan goes up to 100%. And doesn't go up that much again.

Comment: run some load on cpu or hack the ventilator at some electronic repair shop

Comment: I was thinking about connecting analog controller to pwm and adjusting the fan manually but it can corrupt the pc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a good idea, for making them warm together. I removed `bumblebee`, And currently using nvidia driver for `Xorg` and `compiz` too. But now, gpu processes need to do *knock knock* more on cpu and it's better. They're at least working together more.